# unable to hide two dimensional marker array in Google API 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
  My marker  is at the end
```

I am unable to hide the marker using setMap,
Error in Console 
Please help!

Thanks in advance

```js
markers[i][j].setMap(null);
markers.setMap(null);
var markers = [
['office', 'Albania', 42.158410, 19.940845],
['production plant', 'Albania', 40.198905, 20.039722],
['R&D service', 'Albania', 41.090835, 19.545337],
['office', 'Algeria', 28.164666, 3.160335]
];

     `Uncaught TypeError: markers[i][j].setMap`
```

Comment: Show more code please.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why do you think the members of your markers array would have a .setMap methode?  They are arrays.

Comment: How do you display the markers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't hide a marker based on the elements in your array.  They don't have .setMap methods.  The markers need to be [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) objects.  When you create the markers, keep references to them in another array (say "gmarkers"), then use that to hide/show them.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/9gsmk28e/) (using your data)

```js
var markers = [
  ['office', 'Albania', 42.158410, 19.940845],
  ['production plant', 'Albania', 40.198905, 20.039722],
  ['R&D service', 'Albania', 41.090835, 19.545337],
  ['office', 'Algeria', 28.164666, 3.160335]
];
var map;
var gmarkers = [];

function toggleMarker() {
  var markerId = parseInt(document.getElementById('markerid').value);
  if (gmarkers[markerId].getMap() == null) {
    gmarkers[markerId].setMap(map);
  } else {
    gmarkers[markerId].setMap(null);
  }
}

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][2], markers[i][3]),
      map: map
    });
    bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(markers[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
    gmarkers.push(marker);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input type="text" id="markerid" value="2" />
<input type="button" onclick="toggleMarker()" value="toggle" />
<div id="map"></div>
```